# Statement of Golfeld's conjecture

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Goldfeld conjecture asserts that
for elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$,

$rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=0$ for $50%$ square free D's

$rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=1$ for $50%$ square free D's

$rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=2$ for $0％$　square free D's

My question is,

$1.$ Does this imply that only a finite number of $E_D$ have a rank greater than $2$?

$2.$ Are there any known examples of elliptic curves where this conjecture has been verified?

Comment: 1. No, only that they have natural density $0$ (I assume natural density is what those percentages mean). For example the squares or the primes have natural density $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$ but there are countably many of them.

Comment: Apparently, Kriz (“supersingular main conjectures, …” on arxiv) established Goldfeld’s conjecture for some elliptic curves. (Just ctrl-f Goldfeld in the paper because it is not short – and obviously check the indicated references.)